# Automatically get a file onto another computer?

Tags: file-sharing

Alright, brace yourself because this is a hard one to explain:

So, I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and my friend is on Windows 7, I need to be able to get a single file onto his computer without him having to stop what he's doing. [Said friend is not close enough for a local network]

Does anyone know how to make this happen?

Is there some sort of shared drive we can have so the file would be available to him [he just needs to have it on his computer/have his computer be able to access it]?

Or perhaps can I write a windows command that makes him access a Direct download link every so often?

*Note this is with his consent, i'm not trying to give him a virus or anything*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand, but I would suggest dropbox or google drive...,
to install google drive try http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html it is long page so try find section 10. Other tweaks / things to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-drive-ocamlfuse
```

Once it's installed, you'll firstly need to authorize it with Google, by running the following command:

```
google-drive-ocamlfuse
```

then make folder where you want to have google drive synchronized and make this folder to sync with google drive:

```
google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/your-drive
```

~/your-drive is folder which will by synchronized

Comment: Mmm, it was sort of what I wanted, but how do I have my friend who is on windows connect to this? [On his hard drive not online on the Google drive website]

Comment: @TheBallistico there's a Google Drive official client for Windows, like Dropbox.